# placeholder is not working with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, placeholder

I make ajax request to my function and when i am echo  it , placeholder is not working see this div is in loop

php:

```
$info=NULL;
//loop-start
$info.='<div class="comment-part" id="commentBox'.$post_id.'"><textarea name="commentq'.$post_id.'" id="commentq'.$post_id.'" class="textarea-style1" placeholder="Comment.."  onkeydown="return runScript1(event,\''.$post_id.'\',\''.$cmt_id.'\')"> </textarea></div>
                   </div>';
echo $info;

//loop-end
```

js:

```
$('#data').append(html);
```

Comment: Does placeholder actually works on textareas? Isn't it only related to input ?

Comment: What is `html` in your JavaScript?

Comment: @NeoPix Placeholder works on textareas, check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_placeholder.asp) link.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly  html 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a space between `<textarea>` tags, so it is inserted into textarea. If you remove it, you will be able to see a placeholder.

```
$info.='<div class="comment-part" id="commentBox'.$post_id.'"><textarea name="commentq'.$post_id.'" id="commentq'.$post_id.'" class="textarea-style1" placeholder="Comment.."  onkeydown="return runScript1(event,\''.$post_id.'\',\''.$cmt_id.'\')"></textarea></div></div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: problem with your code is you have space between "**textarea**" tags and at the end you added two close div but you have only one open div

```
$info.='<div class="comment-part" id="commentBox'.$post_id.'">
<textarea  name="commentq'.$post_id.'" id="commentq'.$post_id.'" class="textarea-style1" placeholder="Describe yourself here..." onkeydown="return runScript1(event,\''.$post_id.'\',\''.$cmt_id.'\')"></textarea></div>';
```

Comment: @JamesDonnelly i explained the changes.thanks dude :)

Comment: @pratik deshai may this help you :)

Comment: its already done by 'marian0 answer, but thanks for your response

Comment: @pratikdeshai ya !!but i am the first who given this answer :) see the given answer time

Comment: @pratikdeshai edit time is for explaination of what i have changed.see comments with "JamesDonnelly".he ask me to explain my changes.thats why i just added explanation,but i given answer before 40 min backs.see actual time